# How to fillna/missing values for an irregular timeseries for a Drug when Half-life is known

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, fill

I have a  dataframe (df) where column A is drug units that is dosed at time point given by Timestamp. I want to  fill the missing values (NaN) with the drug concentration given the half-life of the drug (180mins). I am  struggling with the code in pandas  . Would really appreciate help and insight. Thanks in advance

```
df
                       A     
Timestamp                                                      
1991-04-21 09:09:00   9.0        
1991-04-21 3:00:00   NaN       
1991-04-21 9:00:00   NaN       
1991-04-22 07:35:00  10.0      
1991-04-22 13:40:00   NaN        
1991-04-22 16:56:00   NaN
```

Given the half -life of the drug is 180 mins. I wanted to fillna(values) as a function of time elapsed and the half life of the drug

something like

```
Timestamp             A     

1991-04-21 09:00:00   9.0  
1991-04-21 3:00:00   ~2.25   
1991-04-21 9:00:00   ~0.55   
1991-04-22 07:35:00  10.0  
1991-04-22 13:40:00   ~2.5   
1991-04-22 16:56:00   ~0.75
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamps are not sorted and I'm assuming this was a typo.  I fixed it below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

text = """TimeStamp                    A     
1991-04-21 09:09:00   9.0        
1991-04-21 13:00:00   NaN       
1991-04-21 19:00:00   NaN       
1991-04-22 07:35:00  10.0      
1991-04-22 13:40:00   NaN        
1991-04-22 16:56:00   NaN  """

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', parse_dates=[0])
```

This is the magic code.

```
# half-life of 180 minutes is 10,800 seconds
# we need to calculate lamda (intentionally mis-spelled)
lamda = 10800 / np.log(2)

# returns time difference for each element
# relative to first element
def time_diff(x):
    return x - x.iloc[0]

# create partition of non-nulls with subsequent nulls
partition = df.A.notnull().cumsum()

# calculate time differences in seconds for each
# element relative to most recent non-null observation
# use .dt accessor and method .total_seconds()
tdiffs = df.TimeStamp.groupby(partition).apply(time_diff).dt.total_seconds()

# apply exponential decay
decay = np.exp(-tdiffs / lamda)

# finally, forward fill the observations and multiply by decay
decay * df.A.ffill()

0     9.000000
1     3.697606
2     0.924402
3    10.000000
4     2.452325
5     1.152895
dtype: float64
```

Comment: THANK U  so much. That was perfect!

Comment: @Pearl glad I could help.